ESP8266 se reinicia
Muy buenas. Estoy usando un esp8266 junto con un modulo CC1101 para enviar datos y otro juego de ellos exactamente iguales para recibir. Uso los pines siguientes:
GPIO15 como Hpsi CS
GPIO13 como Hpsi MOSI
GPIO12 como Hpsi MISO
GPIO14 como Hpsi CLK
GPIO04 como pin receptor.
El problema es que cuando configuro los pines:GPIO06, GPIO07, GPIO11, GPIO08, GPIO09 y GPIO10 como salidas(todos ellos o solo alguno) el esp8266 se me reinicia periódicamente tras enviarle la programación. Si no los configuro el equipo no se reinicia y trabaja correctamente.
Esos últimos pines son: Spi CLK, Spi MISO, Spi CS0, Spi MOSI, HSPIHD y HSPIWP. Es como si tuvieran el mismo uso que los primeros y hubiera un conflicto. He usado:
ELECHOUSE_cc1101.setSpiPin(14, 12, 13, 15);
intentando establecer los pines que uso para que no se reinicie pero sin efecto.
¿Alguien puede indicarme a que se debe y si puedo utilizar los primeros pines para el modulo CC1101 y los segundos pines como salidas?

Los pines del ESP8266 son medio complicados. Revisa está página y cerciorate de que los estás usando según sus posibilidades: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-pinout-reference-gpios/

Gracias, es una pagina genial y no la conocía, pero los pines están igual que yo los había conectado. He intentado establecer los pines del segundo bloque para conectarme al CC1101 y así liberar los primeros y dejarlos como salida, pero no funciona. El equipo se resetea igual.

Puede haber infinidad de razones imposibles de determinar sin el código y el circuito a la vista. Por ejemplo, puede que loop() contenga retardos o esperas que disparen el watchdog.
